# Dispose opened files in Textract?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I write electron application and use [Textract](https://github.com/dbashford/textract) to open text files. What I do currently:

```
        var textract = require('textract');    
        private getData(fileName, type) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                textract.fromFileWithPath(fileName, (error,text) => {
                    return error ? reject(error) : resolve(text);
                })
            })
        }
```

I'm just thinking - do I need to somehow care about closing these files? What if I need to open 1000 files at the same time? Can't find anything in their docs.

Thank you.

Comment: Does Textract work with Electron, cross-platform, i.e. Windows, Mac and Linux? Does it add native modules that might make packaging complex?  (Sorry I don't know the answer to your question, but I'd be very surprised if you had to: a function taking a filename should handle both open and closing.)